# Excel - getting a column to 'follow' inserting or deleting a row in a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

A difficult one to explain in an uncomplicated manner, but here goes:

I have two worksheets and in the first sheet, one of the columns contains lengthy product descriptions - and this description needs to be 15 characters or less as it will be submitted for use in a database where the field length is fixed.

I therefore have a second worksheet which is basically used to play around with shortening the product descriptions and this sheet simply copies the entire product description column (from the main worksheet) into let us say Column B with an =LEN count in Column C ... and then in Column D I might play around with different wordings until the character count from an =LEN in Column E is no more than 15 (this is then automatically copied back to a column called "Shortened Name" on the main sheet.

Problem is if a row is inserted or deleted on the main sheet (let's assume this change was made on Row 10), Column B on the second sheet reflects this change as it is just copying whatever is on the main sheet, but now B10 would theoretically show some new product name according to what was inserted/deleted over on the main sheet, but D10 will still have the previously typed shortened word corresponding to whatever was previously in B10 as it has no link to the changes made in Column B on the whole.

Naturally on a spreadsheet containing a few thousand rows of products, going out of sync like this is impossible to manage manually.

Is there any way to hold some sort of relationship between columns, so that once locked together as such, they follow each other if that makes sense?
Almost like permanent grouping - so if an entire Row is deleted or inserted in the source sheet the same row is inserted or deleted on a second sheet (even though in my case, this second sheet is only monitoring and copying a single Row from the source sheet).

I hope this all makes enough sense for any tips as to where I should start researching this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is a lengthy question / explanation, the answer seems to be a lot shorter.

To keep a cell referencing a certain other cell and not be affected by changes at the source location you have to "lock" the row (or column reference).

If your reference is `D10` even as simple as in `=D10` you can change it to `=D$10` to lock the row number so that it doesn't change even if the data at `D10` moves e.g. due to a row insertion above it.
**With one caveat: the reference source must NOT be in the same sheet!**
That is more complicated than described here...

The same goes for columns, so `=$D10` would stop the column from changing, and of course `=$D$10` would stop either column or row reference to change.

If you edit a formula and wish to have the `$`-signs present, just hit <kbd>F4</kbd> once. If you hit it repeatedly you'll see it change the "stoppers" through all possible combinations.

*The same is slightly different in LibreOffice: hold <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (right alt) while hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>*